# What was defined first and how? The ampere or the vacuum permeability?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, units

I've been looking up the history and evolution of the seven base units and am currently checking out the ampere. What I've found is that 1A is defined as the current in a wire which would experience a force equivalent to this formula:

$$F=\frac{\mu_0 I_1 I_2l}{2\pi r}$$
which is $2\times 10^{-7}$N when all other values are 1.

But since this definition is dependent on vacuum permeability, I tried looking for how the value of this was defined and either came across the same formula or Ampere's circuital law... which also has current in it.

I understand the force can be measured with a balance or a weight, but currents are measured with an ammeter, which if I'm not wrong, is a modified/evolved galvanometer, which is also calibrated based on weight balances(?) upon the force exerted by a current carrying wire, so it's all starting to feel like an ouroboros to me.

Any help? My knowledge base is basically at the level of a Cambridge A level graduate, with a bit more due to compulsory courses in university.

(I asked [this question on PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797061/371600) and was redirected here.)

Comment: When you say ampere you mean the unit ampere or any of the first units used to measure current?

Comment: I think you can easily find on the internet when the ampere unit was formalized and when the Ampère force law was established (it was established without $\mu_0$ and without amps). So the question is now when was $\mu_0$ established.

Comment: Worth reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability#Systems_of_units_and_historical_origin_of_value_of_%CE%BC0

Comment: Ah, so the ampere was defined to be a tenth of the emu/abampere, and then $\mu_0$ was chosen to align itself with that. Although, it isn't quite explained how $k_m$ was later written as $\mu_0/2\pi$. It seemed to have come out of nowhere in this particular text. Any leads on that? (Also sorry for the delay. Got busy.)

Comment: Ampère force law is from 1823 (no units attached). The formalization of the ampère is from 1893  Electrical Congress (IEC) in Chicago. In between there were many systems of units. Note that the constant has to be chosen to be consistent with your units of force and units used in electric phenomena (charge). I still have not found if $\mu_0$ predates 1893.

Comment: Hmm, the whole picture is starting to seem less like a gradual evolution like the meter, and more like a messy bush that several neighbors came and trimmed down at the same time. Weird analogy aside, I meant to say that there seemed to have been a messy cluster of measurement standards, until the formalization occurred where both ampere and $\mu_0$ were defined together with convenient numbers (such as $2\times10^{-7}$ N) to maintain their approximate relationships from older experiments. At least that's what seems like to me atm.

Comment: I agree it is very messy and I cannot find a table with historical measurements of $\mu_0$. If I find something I'll report back. Note that Maxwell did not use $\mu_0$.